# Google access token verification at server end

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

Is there a way to verify the access token retrieved from android application with google login to be verified that it is of the authenticated user.
The process given is to use the following url and pass the access token in the parameter like https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo?id_token=[id_token]. 
But the problem with this is that the result of it will only give me information that is already present with me which would eventually be same as retrieved from the android google apis. So I suppose that doesn't help me to verify the user. 
Is there any other api/process through which we can verify the user who is logging in.